# Matlab filter cellarray?

Tags: matlab, sorting, filtering

I have bellow output of my cellarray.

```
 a = {'100.000000', '23.860477', '23.924062', '41.759920', '46.911883', '48.074160'};
```

I want to filter this array using `cellfun` function with condition if value is greater then 75 will stay and rest will stripped

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please show us so we can help you better than by giving you the code. thanks!

Comment: Yes I tried below code:

a= cellfun(@(x)(x>=75),a);

but following array occured
Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

I have also check classtype of my a varialble and its says 'cell'

Comment: Do you need the contents of your cell to remain strings or can they be converted to a numeric data type?

Comment: Yes no need its remain strings.... can be converted to numeric data type...

Comment: I would recommend using [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) and then using [Amro's answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21126338/2748311)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really quite trivial, but I did not find duplicate that gives a really strait-forward answer, so I might just write it here.

```
Indexes = find(arrayfun(@(idx) str2double(YourCell{idx}) > 75, 1:size(YourCell,2)));
```

Or I think it might be easier + faster to do:

```
T = str2double(YourCell);
Indexes = find(T > 75);
```

The Indexes should allow you to create a matrix or cell using the `vertcat` or `horzcat` to create the new cell/matrix you want.

YourCell = {'1' '2' '3' '56' '76' '87'}

```
Indexes =

 5     6
```

Comment: @excaza True, I made a mistake as I did not have Matlab application by my side, I just answered and forgot. There was another error with size(YourCell,1) which I have fixed.